Can I reduce execution time of these NDSolve precision runs?
I'm working on an NDSolve project with high precision but the integration takes a lot of time and wondering if there's a quicker way to integrate the DEs numerically?  In the case below, the integration is a closed $6\pi$ circuit over a branch of $w(z)$ given implicitly as
$$
9-7w+\left(7-2 z-4 z^2-1 z^3\right) w^2+\left(7 z-2 z^3\right) w^3=0
$$
The integration path is very smooth as you can see by the yellow $\texttt{medial[t]}$ contour over the branch in the plot below.
Here's my timing at $4.5$ GHz:
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
 \text{Precision} & \text{Time(min)} \\
\hline
 50 & 0.025 \\
 100 & 0.159 \\
 200 & 6.14 \\
 250 & 55.6 \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$
I would like to go up to $300$ digits of working precision but $250$ is already taking about an hour and from the trend $300$ would appear to take much longer.  Any improvements at $250$ or below would still be great however.  The following code uses Method -> "StiffnessSwitching" as without it I encounter the message:

NDSolve::ndcf: Repeated convergence test failure

And I also commented out MaxStepSize->1/1000 as this increases execution time.
implicitF[z_, w_] :=9 - 7 w + w^3 (7 z - 2 z^3) + w^2 (7 - 2 z - 4 z^2 - z^3);
tStart = Pi/6;
tEnd = Pi/6 + 6 Pi;
rNorm = 85/100;
zFun[t_] := rNorm Exp[I t];
zStart = zFun[tStart];
theRoots = 
  w /. NSolve[implicitF[zStart, w] == 0, w, WorkingPrecision -> 700];
wStart = theRoots[[1]];
wDeriv = 
  w'[t] == ((-(D[implicitF[z, w], z]/D[implicitF[z, w], w]) (D[
         zFun[t], t])) /. {w -> w[t], z -> zFun[t]});
pTable = Table[Print["Analyzing precision: ", wpVal];
   at = AbsoluteTiming[
     medialSol = 
       NDSolveValue[{wDeriv, w[tStart] == wStart}, 
        w, {t, tStart, tEnd}, MaxSteps -> 20000000, 
        InterpolationOrder -> All, 
        WorkingPrecision -> wpVal,(*MaxStepSize->1/1000,*)
        Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"];];
   Print["     time: ", at[[1]]/60];
   {wpVal, at[[1]]/60}, {wpVal, {50, 100, 150, 200, 250}}];



From aborting PrintTemporary@Dynamic@{time = Clock@Infinity, murf, time*(tEnd - tStart)/(murf - tStart)}; foo = NDSolveValue[{wDeriv, w[tStart] == wStart},    w, {t, tStart, tEnd}, MaxSteps -> 20000000,    InterpolationOrder -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 300,    Method -> "StiffnessSwitching", StepMonitor :> (murf = t)] after about 50 sec., I estimate the total time to be around 250 min. from time*(tEnd - tStart)/(murf - tStart). It's about the same for Method -> "Extrapolation". If you can wait 4-5 hours, you might have a solution. With the monitors, you have an idea how it's going

@Michael E2:  Thanks for that.  I can certainly wait 4-5 hours,  but that's just for a single branch.  This one has 8 and I am studying other functions with even more branching. My progress would increase if I could speed-up the computations even for the 250 or lower.  I don't absolutely need 300, was just wondering if others more knowledgeable knew of a faster way.

I don't know a way to speed up NDSolve. I think the precision goal entails very small steps and there's no way around that. Could you do something like this?: Construct a low-preciison approximation with NDSolve and polish the value with FindRoot? Presumably the function call would be slower than the interpolating function produced by NDSolve, but maybe it would be an overall win.

Polishing the medial contour via FindRoot is a quicker way to compute the 300-digit terms:  Takes 90 minutes (in parallel) to compute 800 of the subsequent integrals at 300 digits using $\texttt{polishMedial}$ compared to 40 minutes computing 800 at 200 digits directly as above.  Only caveat is possibility of Newton method converging to wrong root but I have other methods of confirming the accuracy of the integrals. .  Thanks for you help Michael!
